# Best way to finish a while loop for api request?

Tags: python-3.x

So i realized after printing my data to json that my api call isnt finishing, how can i go about creating a count down timer? I am using the cursor value which doesnt really change and i cannot use the rel links, if im able to get the totalPages, can i count down based off the variable or is there a better way to end the python api requests?

my current method doesnt really work since there's always a cursor, but it works as far as never ending the while loop

i thought i could do count = totalpage -1 but that isnt working either, this is what i have so far

```
from curses import raw, reset_shell_mode
from http import server
from turtle import pd
import requests, sys
import urllib3
from pathlib import Path  
import json
from datetime import datetime
from requests import Session
from typing import Any, List, Tuple, Dict
import pandas as pd
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter, Retry
from collections import Counter


# disable urllib3 warnings for SSL
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
sys.path.append('/Users/s153152/Documents/Workspace/kpi/rapid7')


def _headers():
    headers = {
            'X-Api-Key': 'key',
            'Content-type':'application/json', 
            'Accept':'*/*'
            }
    return headers

def _request():

    third_party_patching_filer = {
    "asset": "asset.tags IN ['osswin'] && asset.os.vendor CONTAINS 'microsoft' && asset.agentKey IS NOT NULL", 
    "vulnerability" : "vulnerability.categories NOT IN ['microsoft patch']"}

    headers = _headers()
    print(headers)
    url1 = f"https://us.api.insight.rapid7.com/vm/v4/integration/assets?&size=50"
    resp = requests.post(url=url1, headers=headers, json=third_party_patching_filer, verify=False).json()

    has_next_cursor = True
    nextKey = ""
    totalpage = resp["metadata"]
    print(totalpage)


    total_server_ip_addresses = []
    osname_server1 = []
    total_critical_vul_osswin = []
    results = []
    
    with requests.Session() as session:
        url2 = f"https://us.api.insight.rapid7.com/vm/v4/integration/assets?&size=50&cursor={nextKey}"

        while has_next_cursor:

            s = requests.Session()
            backoff_factor=0.3
            retries = Retry(total=10, backoff_factor=backoff_factor, status_forcelist=[ 502, 503, 504 ])
            s.mount(url2, HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
            s = s.post(url=url2, headers=headers, json=third_party_patching_filer, verify=False)
            print(s.status_code)
            s = s.json()

            rel_last = s["metadata"]
            cursor = s["metadata"]

            if "cursor" in cursor:

                nextKey = cursor["cursor"]
                totalResources = cursor["totalResources"]
                count = totalpage -1

                print(f"next key {nextKey}, total resourcs {totalResources}")
                print(f"{count}")
                #print(desktop_support)

                for data in s["data"]:
                    for tags in data['tags']:
                        
                        if tags["name"] == 'OSSWIN':
                            try:
                                osname_server = data['host_name']
                                server_host_ip_address = data['ip']
                                critical_vuln_osswin = data['critical_vulnerabilities']
                                os_type = data['os_type']
                                data = {
                                    'ip_address': server_host_ip_address,
                                    'os_name': osname_server,
                                    'critical_vuln': critical_vuln_osswin,
                                    'os_type': os_type
                                }
                                results.append(data)
                            except Exception as e:
                                f"Possibly no ip address, error {e}"
                            #print(f"Server asset: {osname_server1}, {total_server_ip_addresses}")
                            
                            with open('server_info.json', 'w') as f:
                                json.dump(results, f, indent=2)

                            #print(data['host_name'])

        else:
            has_next_cursor = False



    return total_server_ip_addresses, sum(total_server_ip_addresses)

def smart_filter():
    test = _request()
    print(test)


smart_filter()
```

count down from variable to finish the api call